# Context is not being applied in Drupal 7

Tags: theming, 7

I searched for my problem so please forgive me, when this is duplicate as I'm newbie and the drupal specific terminology isn't my native tounge :)

I set up a delta "delta_theme" for a theme I'm using.

Then I created a simple context "test" with condition "path: node/1" and reaction "delta: delta_theme".

But whenever I visit localhost/node/1 the theme for this node does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

Do you need more info? Just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're trying to change theme based on specific nodes, have a look at the Theme Key module.